# Fallo en inserción de registro SQL

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy creado un formulario de inserción de datos he imágenes a través de AJAX, consigo que los ficheros suban al servidor, pero no se inserta el registro en la BD. Normalmente no me pasa esto, no se si hay algo que se me a pasado por alto.

**El HTML**

```
           <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="editacasa" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Referencia</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="referencia" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Titulo</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="titulo1" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Subtitulo</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="subtitulo" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Superficie</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="superficie" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Habitaciones</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="habitaciones">
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Baños</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="banos" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Ascensor</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="ascensor" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="label35">Precio</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont35 corpiii" name="precio" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="label35">Descripción</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div id="mensaje"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="col-md-12 arreglaUser22" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <h3 class="editTesAA">Foto Grande</h3>
            <img src="../images/pisos/no-foto.gif" alt="" class="imgArgljo" style="border-radius: 0%; width:100%;">
            <input type="file" class="inputfile" id="imagen" name="imagen" placeholder="Imagen" value="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 arreglaUser22" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <h3 class="editTesAA">Foto Izquierda</h3>
            <img src="../images/pisos/no-foto.gif" alt="" class="imgArgljo" style="border-radius: 0%; width:100%;">
            <input type="file" class="inputfile" id="imagen2" name="imagen2" placeholder="Imagen" value="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 arreglaUser22">
            <h3 class="editTesAA">Foto Derecha</h3>
            <img src="../images/pisos/no-foto.gif" alt="" class="imgArgljo" style="border-radius: 0%; width:100%;">
            <input type="file" class="inputfile" id="imagen3" name="imagen3" placeholder="Imagen" value="">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 arreglaUser22">
            <h3 class="editTesAA">QR</h3>
            <img src="../images/pisos/no-foto.gif" alt="" class="imgArgljo" style="border-radius: 0%; width:100%;">
            <input type="file" class="inputfile" id="imagen4" name="imagen4" placeholder="Imagen" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="btnguardar2"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default pad-guardar">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

**El código AJAX**

```
        $(function(){
            $("#editacasa").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this);
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("editacasa"));
                formData.append("dato", "valor");
                //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/insertar-cartel-venta.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                      /*$("#loader").html("<div class='ui active inline loader'></div>")*/
                      $('body').loadingModal({
                        position: 'auto',
                        text: 'Creando el cartel...',
                        color: '#fff',
                        opacity: '0.7',
                        backgroundColor: 'gray',
                        animation: 'chasingDots'
                      });
                    },
                })
                    .done(function(res){
                        $("#mensaje").html(res);
                        toastr["success"]("Cartel añadido", "Mensaje")
                        setTimeout(function () {
                               window.location.href = "cartel-venta-vivienda.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                           }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                    });
            });
        });
```

**Y por último el PHP**

```
include "../../conexion/conecta.php";

$referencia= $_POST['referencia'];
$titulo1 = $_POST['titulo1'];
$titulo2 = $_POST['subtitulo'];
$superficie = $_POST['superficie'];
$habitaciones = $_POST['habitaciones'];
$banos = $_POST['banos'];
$ascensor = $_POST['ascensor'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
 {

     //obtenemos el archivo a subir
     $file = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
     $file2 = $_FILES['imagen2']['name'];
     $file3 = $_FILES['imagen3']['name'];
     $file4 = $_FILES['imagen4']['name'];
     //comprobamos si existe un directorio para subir el archivo
     //si no es así, lo creamos
     if(!is_dir("../../images/carteles/"))
         mkdir("../../images/carteles/", 0777);


     //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
     if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],"../../images/carteles/".$file))
     if ($file2 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name'],"../../images/carteles/".$file2))
     if ($file3 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name'],"../../images/carteles/".$file3))
     if ($file4 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name'],"../../images/carteles/".$file4))
     {
        sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
        $usuario_cargo_foto = true;
     }

     //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido


    }else{
        echo "Error Processing Request";
    }

  $results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO cartelVV (titulo1, titulo2, superficie, habitaciones, banos, ascensor, descripcion, precio, referencia, foto1, foto2, foto3, qr)
  VALUES ('$titulo1', '$titulo2', '$superficie', '$habitaciones', $banos',
    '$ascensor', '$descripcion', '$precio', '$referencia', '$file', '$file2', '$file3', '$file4' )");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira en values, la variable $banos'  faltan las comillas de apertura, la de cierre sí que está. 
Desde el móvil no puedo mirar más, pero eso puede fastidiar el insert

Comment: Tan fácil como esto! pues no lo encontraba, muchas gracias!